# Ajax POST --> Passing no data

Tags: php, ajax

I'm a beginner so tell me if i'm doing something fundamentally wrong.
I am trying to post data with ajax. The post itself works, but it is not passing any data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'processwifi.php',
                    data:{'postid': postid}, 
            success: function(response){
                    alert('it works');
                    }
                    });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the processwifi.php

```
<?php
            $id = isset($_POST["postid"]);

            $link = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","***","***","secretariaat");
                    if (!$link) {
                        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
                        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
                        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
                    exit;
                    }

                $sql = "UPDATE wifi SET gebruikt='1' WHERE wifi.id='$id'";

                    if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                        echo "Update of record is '$id' successfully";
                        } else {
                            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                          }

                mysqli_close($link); 



                //Redirect result page
            //header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            //header('Location: wificode.php');
?>
```

Could anyone help me ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This: `$id = isset($_POST["postid"]);` will set `$id` to `true` or `false` depending on if `$_POST['postid']` is posted ot not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not yet stated what `postid` is supposed to indicate. You're trying to obtain a value from a `variable / field / property` which is never declared and set.

In the following example I've set the value of `postid` to `1`. 
https://jsfiddle.net/n5rc6u3g/

When trying to debug the "Network" tab, you'll notice the sent Form Data indicates `postid` as `1`.

Also, there is a fundamental mistake in your backend code. You're trying to obtain the `postid` using the method `isset($_POST["postid"])`
The signature from the `isset` method is:

```
bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )
```

Meaning it returns a `boolean`, being either `true` or `false`. Which in turn indicated whether the value is set and not null. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Thanks, it works now. And even better, I understand my mistakes to the fullest

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable `postid`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            var postid = 10; // define postid here
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'processwifi.php',
                    data:{'postid': postid}, 
            success: function(response){
                    alert('it works');
                    }
                    });
        });
    });
</script>
```